# PIP Python not installing latest version of package

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

So installing the JIRA python package.
The PyPi repo says there is a 3.5.2
but when asking for the specific version I get. the below... the generic install give me 3.2 which is not the latest version.

```
pip install jira==3.5.2 or pip install jira
```

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> jira==3.5.2 (from versions: 0.1.0, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.20, 0.21,
> 0.22, 0.23, 0.25, 0.28, 0.30, 0.31, 0.32, 0.33, 0.35, 0.36, 0.37, 0.38, 0.39, 0.40, 0.41, 0.42, 0.43, 0.44, 0.45, 0.46, 0.47, 0.48, 0.49, 0.50, 1.0.3, 1.0.7.dev20160607111203, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9, 1.0.10, 1.0.11, 1.0.13, 1.0.14, 1.0.15, 2.0.0.0rc3, 2.0.0.0rc4, 2.0.0.0rc6, 2.0.0.0rc7, 2.0.0.0rc9, 2.0.0.0rc10, 2.0.0, 2.0.1.0rc1, 3.0.0.0a0, 3.0a1, 3.0a2, 3.0.1, 3.1.0rc1, 3.1.1, 3.2.0) ERROR: No matching distribution found for jira==3.5.2

Not understanding why..

Comment: do you have python 3.6 or 3.7?

Comment: When you try to `pip install packge_name` , it will looks for versions that is supported by your target python version. It seems like [jira 3.5.2 requires python >=3.8](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/blob/095565a701bb500eb51a15a45276658d721c8038/setup.cfg#L47). So I am sure that you are using Python < 3.8

Comment: what version of python do you have?

Comment: if you don't force the version, just try to run 'pip install Jira', it will install the compatible version available. Is there a reason you want a specific version ? you may have to upgrade python first